# Query: Join, Concat, but getting Results

Tags: mysql, sql, null

**Hi there,**

I'm having a problem here. I'm working on a Search option. I Can search on First Name, Last Name, Company Name and Numberplate. I Only want to show the left side, also the customer information, which I'm getting with the following Query. However, when the Customer doesn't have a Numberplate, the Customer is not displayed. Is there a way to prevent that?

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
FROM adressen AS A 
OUTER JOIN fahrzeuge AS F 
ON F.fa_kunden_id = A.ad_id 
WHERE CONCAT(coalesce(A.ad_name), coalesce(A.ad_vorname),coalesce(A.ad_firma), coalesce(F.fa_kennzeichen)) LIKE '%"+wndHauptfenster.textfield_suche.Text+"%'
```

I've tried using IFNULL too, however, this will result in 'No results', even for customers with a Car:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
FROM adressen AS A 
OUTER JOIN fahrzeuge AS F 
ON F.fa_kunden_id = A.ad_id 
WHERE CONCAT(coalesce(A.ad_name), coalesce(A.ad_vorname),coalesce(A.ad_firma), coalesce(ifnull(F.fa_kennzeichen, 'leer'))) LIKE '%"+wndHauptfenster.textfield_suche.Text+"%'
```

**UPDATE:** After trying a given Solution, it will not find anything at all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
FROM adressen AS A 
OUTER JOIN fahrzeuge AS F 
ON F.fa_kunden_id = A.ad_id 
WHERE CONCAT(coalesce(A.ad_name, ''), coalesce(A.ad_vorname, ''),coalesce(A.ad_firma, ''), coalesce(F.fa_kennzeichen, '')) LIKE '%"+wndHauptfenster.textfield_suche.Text+"%'
```

The Columns in Adressen:

- `ad_vorname` contains `Max`
- `ad_name` contains `Mustermann`
- `ad_firma` contains `Testfirma Inc`
- `fa_kennzeichen` contains nothing. The row which the query is searching for doesn't exist.

Comment: Is `fa_kennzeichen` numberplate?

Comment: Yes. That's the Numberplate.

Comment: Some sample data might help then, with examples of records that aren't being returned.

Comment: You have used _coalesce(A.ad_firma)_ , which will still return NULL if A.ad_firma is null. As such it doesn't seem to do anything useful. Change that to _coalesce(A.ad_firma, '')_ , to swap NULL for an empty string. Doing this you do not need the IFNULL clause

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the post, where I tried what @Kickstart said. I've also added more data for information purpose.

Comment: I still don't see where you've utilized the keyword `LEFT` suggested by KickStart.  Also is this query passed in via PHP or something?  I don't see how the string `%"+wndHauptfenster.textfield_suche.Text+"%` would likely match I assume you want the VALUE of the .text.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
FROM adressen AS A 
OUTER JOIN fahrzeuge AS F 
ON F.fa_kunden_id = A.ad_id 
WHERE CONCAT(coalesce(A.ad_name,''), coalesce(A.ad_vorname,''),coalesce(A.ad_firma,''), coalesce(F.fa_kennzeichen,'')) LIKE '%"+wndHauptfenster.textfield_suche.Text+"%'
```

Answer (score 0):

OUTER JOIN is a syntax error. Should be LEFT OUTER JOIN, or abbreviated to LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
FROM adressen AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fahrzeuge AS F 
ON F.fa_kunden_id = A.ad_id 
WHERE CONCAT(coalesce(A.ad_name, ''), coalesce(A.ad_vorname, ''),coalesce(A.ad_firma, ''), coalesce(F.fa_kennzeichen, '')) LIKE '%"+wndHauptfenster.textfield_suche.Text+"%'
```